# Error: Creating simple Play project in IntelliJ

Tags: playframework-2.3

I am new to play framework and SBT build tools.. I wanted to test simple Hello world using IntelliJ idea ...But having following issue...Could you please tell me what is going wrong...

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: sbt-run-support-210#sbt-run-support-210_2.10;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
Invalid response.
Invalid response.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Use activator to prepare Idea project: $ activator idea
2. Import project in Idea as existed project

Documentation for version 2.3 is a little bit confusing. 
See for 2.1, it's relevant (except activator command) https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/IDE#IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. Actually problem was installing SBT tools and setting up proper path for IntelliJ and version of JDK. I recently moved to Mac environment from windows.Somehow misconfigured everything. I downloaded it from scala website and set up manual path in bash_profile.  It is always good to use Homebrew or MacPorts to install SBT and JDK.
I installed SBT and JDK using Homebrew and now it works fine. dont have to set up any path in bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create Play application in the Idea, instead use the console tool like: `activator new` and after choosing the options in the tool and creating the project just import it in Idea as **Import project from external model** > **SBT**

Comment: I think I'm only men in the world using activator new in command line and import that in intellij. I'm glade to see you bro

Comment: `activator` (former `play`) cmd always does it in right way, any IDE can be outdated and do not reflect the newest changes to the framework.